# Referencing class' function from an element of a linked list C#

Tags: c#, delegates, function-pointers

For a purpose of my university project I need to implement a cyclical linked list, which holds some specific elements. The problem: I want an element of the linked list to have a pointer to a function from the class which creates it. To show the problem in pseudo-C#:

```
using System;
class Game{
    internal void state1(){
        Console.WriteLine("Executing state1 code");
    }
    internal void state2(){
        Console.WriteLine("Executing state1 code");
    }
Element elem1 = new Elem(state1);
Element elem2 = new Elem(state2);
elem1.Call();
elem2.Call();
}

class Element{
    FunctionPointer Call = null;
    Element(FunctionPointer function){
        Call = function;
    }
}
```

I've tried to use a Delegate, but didn't quite get it right. Is it possible to somehow achieve this using Interfaces?

My delegate try:

```
using System;
public delegate void MyDelegate();

class Game{
    internal void state1(){
        Console.WriteLine("Executing state1 code");
    }
    internal void state2(){
        Console.WriteLine("Executing state1 code");
    }
    Element elem = new Element(new MyDelegate(state1));
}

class Element{
    MyDelegate functionPointer = null;
    Element(MyDelegate func){
        functionPointer =  func;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt with delegate?

Comment: @D-Shih The Game class is a main subclass which holds quite a bit of parameters. I want to have a cyclical linked list with states, where a state calls a specific function from Game class, and after the execution goes into the next state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  Using a delegate would be something like...

```
public class Game
{
    private Element _element = null;

    public Game()
    {
        _element = new Element(state1);
    }
    internal void state1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing state1 code");
    }
    internal void state2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing state2 code");
    }
}

public class Element
{
    public delegate void FunctionPointer();
    private FunctionPointer _function = null;

    public Element(FunctionPointer function)
    {
        _function = new FunctionPointer(function);
        _function();            
    }
}
```

using interfaces...

```
public interface IGame
{
    void state1();
    void state2();
}
public class Game : IGame
{
    private Element _element = null;

    public Game()
    {
        _element = new Element(this);
    }
    public void state1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing state1 code");
    }
    public void state2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing state1 code");
    }
}

public class Element
{
    private IGame _game = null;

    public Element(IGame game)
    {
        _game = game;
        _game.state1();
    }
}
```

in my opinion interfaces are better

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I don't know if I'm implementing something incorrectly, but while compiling the first code I get an error: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field. And when it comes to implementation through an interface, in this case I can't specify which state should the element call (I want to be able to specify which state should be executed through an element while creating it).

Comment: you would want to use the delegate if you want to dynamically choose which method to call.  I don't see anything wrong with the code...did you add something?

Comment: Found my mistake, I tried to initialize it outside of the constructor. Thanks a ton, you solved my problem!